# How to trigger a drop event for any of the item dragged and dropped inside any of the child div inside a main dev in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of items like

```
<ul>
  <li draggable="true">item 1</li>
  <li draggable="true">item 2</li>
  <li draggable="true">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

and a container `div` with divisions as child like

```
<div class="container" ondrop="drop(event)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child-row">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i trigger an event or just call an alert when any of the list item is dragged and dropped inside any of the child `div` inside the container class? Can anyone help me?

EDIT: My script is

```
function drop(event) {
  alert();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the javascript that you've written so far.

Comment: added the script @Olian04

Comment: Try my answer @Hareesh

Comment: You just have to cancel the dragenter and dragover events on the parent container and it will work for the container and its children, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

For the drop event to occur on a div element, you must cancel both the `dragenter` and `dragover` events using `event.preventDefault()`, according to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#droptargets):

> If you want to allow a drop, you must prevent the default handling by cancelling the event. You can do this either by returning false from an attribute-defined event listener, or by calling the event's preventDefault() method ... Calling the preventDefault() method during both a dragenter and dragover event will indicate that a drop is allowed at that location.

You can do this by querying your container using `document.querySelector('.container')` and then attach the proper event listners with `target.addEventListener()`, or attach them directly in the HTML.

You only need to do this for the parent container and it will work for the children too.

```js
function drop(event) {
  const item = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  const target = event.target.querySelector('.target');
  if (target) {
    target.textContent = `${target.textContent}${target.textContent && ','} ${item}`;
  }
}

function drag(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.textContent);
}

function cancel(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child-row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
.target {
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the list items in the rectangles:</p>
<ul>
  <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">item 1</li>
  <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">item 2</li>
  <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">item 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragenter="cancel(event)" ondragover="cancel(event)">
  Container <span class="target"></span>
  <div class="row">
    Row <span class="target"></span>
    <div class="child-row">
      Child Row <span class="target"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
         <div class="child-row" onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()} onDrop={(e) => {console.log(e, 'inside');}}>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <ul>
    <li draggable="true">item 1</li>
    <li draggable="true">item 2</li>
    <li draggable="true">item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

Give the child div a height and width to identify the dropevent

```
.child-row{
 height: 51px;
 width: 147px;
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Will this work if the list is dropped inside `<div class="child-row">` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like below -

```js
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  //console.log(data)
}
```

```css
.container .child-row{
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul{
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <li id="item1" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true">item 1</li>
  <li id="item2" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true">item 2</li>
  <li id="item3" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true">item 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="container" ondrop="drop(event)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="child-row" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```